# Latex Tables in ipe

Tags: ipe

I'm making a presentation in ipe. I have a table from a .tex document that I would like to include in ipe document. Is there any way to use the tabular environment or something similar in ipe?

Comment: I'd never head of IPE but http://ipe7.sourceforge.net/ says it can include fragments of latex, did you try it?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ipe7 is exactly what I'm using. You can embed pretty complicated fragments of latex, but tabular complains because its not in an outer par environment

Comment: no `tabular` would not give that error, `table` would, but you don't need `table` for a self-standing fragment. The whole point of table is to float to another page. I see you answered already!

Answer (score 6):

I was copying and pasting the tex from a paper, which included \table{} which pdflatex complained about, saying it's not in an outer par environment. By just using tabular, ipe was happy to include it, after I cleaned up some other issues that the latex code also had.

```
\begin{tabular}{|l l|l|l|} 
\hline 
Query Type  &                 &  Query Time         & Space   \\ \hline
Orthogonal: &   Standard  & $O(\log^{d-1} n)$ & $O(n \log^{d-1} n)$     \\  
    &  SD fixed $m$                  & $O(m \cdot \log ^d n)$     &  $O(m \cdot n \log^{d-1} n)$     \\
    &  SD variable $m$               & $O(m \cdot \log ^d n)$     &  $O(n \log ^d n)$       \\ 
    &  SD size est.                  & $O(\log ^{d+1} n \log U)$  & $O(n \log^{d} n \log U)$         \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just a small addition to your answer.

If you would need to include a `pmatrix` instead of `tabular` into your figure, you also need to ask IPE to include the amsmath package. This is simple (taken from [here](https://mailman.science.uu.nl/pipermail/ipe-discuss/2016-April/001783.html)). Click on Edit > Document properties (alternatively, press Ctrl+Shift+P) and type `\usepackage{amsmath}` into the "Latex Preamble" field.

You can also use this for changing fonts or doing anything else you normally do in the preamble of your LaTeX document.